# How to use and process repeating XML elements to create other elements with a shell script?

Tags: xml, shell, xpath, xmlstarlet

Let's say I would like to create the next XML file with a (POSIX-compliant) shell script:

```
<xml>
    <item>
        <title>The Turning Point to a Cross Fade in a Carpark</title>
        <slug>the-turning-point-to-a-cross-fade-in-a-carpark</slug>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>The Cycle Continues in One Direction</title>
        <slug>the-cycle-continues-in-one-direction</slug>
    </item>
</xml>
```

But I only have the next one:

```
<xml>
    <item>
        <title>The Turning Point to a Cross Fade in a Carpark</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>The Cycle Continues in One Direction</title>
    </item>
</xml>
```

With XMLStarlet [`edit --update`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html) (and only with `--update`) I can use XPath expressions instead of string values in the form:

```
xml ed -u '/xml/item/slug' -x '../title/text()'
```

but XPath 2.0 string functions doesn't seem to work (`xmlXPathCompOpEval: function lower-case not found`). How could I then iterate through all  blocks and use the text value of the `<title>` elements to generate the `<slug>` elements? How can I do this with the fewest `xml` actions?

Comment: [translate()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

`translate(../title,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-')`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've got so far with `translate()` and `normalize-space()`.

```
xml ed -a '/xml/item/title' \
       -t 'elem' \
       -n 'slug' \
       -v '' \
\
       -u '/xml/item/slug' \
       -x 'translate(
               normalize-space(
                   translate(
                       ../title/text(),
                       "AÁBCDEÉFGHIÍJKLMNOÓÖŐPQRSTUÚÜŰVWXYZ-+.,:;!()&#",
                       "aábcdeéfghiíjklmnoóöőpqrstuúüűvwxyz  "
                   )
               ),
               " ",
               "-"
           )'
```

The idea behind this is

1. to convert the text to lower-case,
2. remove all accentuated letters and special symbols,
3. convert every dash and plus sign to spaces,
4. and remove all unnecessary spaces.

Making up that character set is far from optimal, as I have to specify every character I want to remove, while I only know the ones that should remain. And how do I put the typewriter apostrophe in the set?!

**I'm open for better ideas.**